# Cannot install mediapipe package in Pycharm terminal or Package installer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm, raspberry-pi4, mediapipe

I am trying to use Mediapipe with python. I originally tried mediapipe-rpi4 which did install successfully. But when I run it I get this error message

Traceback (most recent call last):

````
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "C:\Users\Isiana\PycharmProjects\FitnessTrainer\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Isiana\PycharmProjects\FitnessTrainer\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings' ```



I then tried to download the regular mediapipe and I am getting this error now:

``` ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe ```

Does anyone know what I am  doing worng?
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The latest version of mediapipe is having an error. So,
you can downgrade your mediapipe version. Here is the command I used:

```
pip install mediapipe==0.8.3.1
```

If you want other versions, Than go https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#history

Thanks.